# Polymer.dart: using strong types for child components throws exception, var works

Tags: dart, polymer

I have two custom components written in Polymer.dart, one is the parent of the other. I want to get a reference to the child component in the parent, but if I use type annotations, I get an exception. On the other hand, if I use the `var` keyword for declaring the variable, it works fine.

The error message and the stack trace that I get when using types:

> Uncaught Error: type 'ChildComponent' is not a subtype of type 'ChildComponent' of 'childComponent'.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> #0      ParentComponent.inserted (package:types_test_lib/parent_component.dart?1375856554489:9:67)
>
> #1      _registerLifecycleInsert. (package:custom_element/custom_element.dart:643:21)
>
> #2      _ZoneBase._runInZone (dart:async/zone.dart:82:17)
>
> #3      _ZoneBase._runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:99:22)
>
> #4      _ZoneBase.executeCallbackGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:62:21)
>
> #5      _RunAsyncZone.runAsync.. (dart:async/zone.dart:205:61)
>
> #6      performMicrotaskCheckpoint (package:observe/src/microtask.dart:36:17)
>
> #7      wrapMicrotask.. (package:observe/src/microtask.dart:58:35)
>
> #8      runZonedExperimental (dart:async/zone.dart:259:53)
>
> #9      runZonedExperimental. (dart:async/zone.dart:256:34)
>
> #10     _ZoneBase._runInZone (dart:async/zone.dart:82:17)
>
> #11     _ZoneBase._runUnguarded (dart:async/zone.dart:102:22)
>
> #12     runZonedExperimental (dart:async/zone.dart:255:30)
>
> #13     wrapMicrotask. (package:observe/src/microtask.dart:54:25)
>
> #14     initPolymer (package:polymer/polymer.dart:72:5)
>
> #15     main (.../D:/workspace/dart/types_test/web/types_test.html:7:22)
>
> Exception: type 'ChildComponent' is not a subtype of type 'ChildComponent' of 'childComponent'.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="parent_component.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="child_component.html"/>
    <script src="packages/polymer/boot.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <parent-component>
      <child-component/>
    </parent-component>

    <script type="application/dart">
      void main() {}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

parent_component.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <polymer-element name="parent-component" extends="div">
      <template></template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="parent_component.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

parent_component.dart:

```
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";
import "child_component.dart";

@CustomTag("parent-component")
class ParentComponent extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  void inserted() {
    var childComponent = host.query("child-component").xtag;
    // !!! ChildComponent childComponent = host.query("child-component").xtag;
  }
}
```

child_component.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <polymer-element name="child-component" extends="div">
      <template></template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="child_component.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

child_component.dart:

```
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

@CustomTag("child-component")
class ChildComponent extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? What can be the problem?

Thanks for any response!

Gabor

Comment: quick guess: what happens if you import child_component.dart as a package: import rather than a relative import?

Comment: The same thing happens. I upgraded my Dart Editor today which gives me a complete stack trace. I updated the question with it. Is this a possible bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, with the error appearing in following code:

```
DivElement templ = query("#myElem");
var ct = templ.xtag;
//CustomTable ct = templ.xtag;
ct.people = [new Person('aaa', 'aaa'), new Person('vvv', 'vvv')];
```

where CustomTable extends PolymerElement

Fortunately, it seems to be fixed in latest SDK and Polymer (I tried SDK 0.6.21.3_r26639 and polymer 0.6.21+3)
I checked your example and it works as well.